# Having trouble proving transitivity

Tags: equivalence-relations

> We have a universal set of lowercase alphabet letters, $U = \{a, b, ... , z\}$ . For sets $A,B \subseteq U$ we can define a relation, $A \sim B$ as long as the number of elements that are in either $A$ or $B$, but not both, is even. Prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation, and describe the equivalence classes.

I've come up with equations for $A \sim B$ and $B\sim C$. For $A \sim B$, I have $|(A \cup B)-(A \cap B)| \equiv 0 \mod2$, and for $B \sim C$, I have $|(B \cup C)-(B \cap C)| \equiv 0 \mod 2$. I've been told to come up with equations for $A\sim B$ and $B \sim C$, then add them to prove $A\sim C$, but I don't know how that's possible. I'm thinking I should end up with $|(A\cup C)-(A \cap C)| \equiv 0 \mod2$, but I don't know how. Perhaps my equations are incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not so difficult to figure out if you draw the complete [Venn diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) and consider all possible intersections. In symbols, it works as follows.

Put $\alpha := A\setminus(B\cup C),$ $\delta := (A\cap C)\setminus B,$ $\gamma := B\setminus(A\cup C),$ $\zeta := (B\cap C)\setminus A,$ $\beta := (A\cap B)\setminus C,$ $\eta := C\setminus(A\cup B).$ Convince yourself with the aid of the aforementioned Venn diagram that all those sets denoted by greek letters are pairwise disjoint, and also that we have:
$$
A\setminus B = \alpha \cup \delta
$$
$$
B\setminus A = \gamma \cup \zeta
$$
$$
B\setminus C = \beta \cup \gamma
$$
$$
C\setminus B = \delta \cup \eta
$$
$$
A\setminus C = \alpha \cup \beta
$$
$$C\setminus A = \eta \cup \zeta
$$
Now, from $A\sim B,$ we conclude
$$
2|\left(|\alpha| + |\delta| + |\gamma| + |\zeta|\right),
$$
and from $B \sim C,$ we conclude
$$
2|\left(|\beta|+|\gamma|+|\delta|+|\eta|\right).
$$
By "adding up" these two statements, we get
$$
2|\left(|\alpha|+|\beta|+|\zeta|+|\eta|+2|\gamma|+2|\delta|\right).
$$
This is equivalent to
$$
2|\left(|\alpha|+|\beta|+|\zeta|+|\eta|\right).
$$
Now, using all the definitions and facts from above, we see that this is equivalent to
$$
2|(|A\Delta C|),\qquad or \qquad A \sim C,
$$
as desired.

Comment: Can you explain why the "2|γ|+2|δ|" disappear when you show that it is equivalent to the next line? I don't understand that part.

Comment: Suppose we have two numbers $j,k\in\mathbb Z.$ Then $2|(j+2k)$ iff $2|j.$ This is so because the statement $2|(2k)$ is always true, for any $k.$ More formally, suppose $2|j$. This then implies ($2|j$ and $2|(2k)$) (since $2|(2k)$ is always true). This implies $2|(j+2k).$ In the other direction, suppose $2|(j+2k).$ This then implies ($2|(j+2k)$ and $2|(2k)$) (again, $2|(2k)$ is always true). This implies $2|(j+2k-2k),$ or $2|j,$ as desired. Now, apply this reasoning to the calculations in my answer.